# Change the color of cite number in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

Does anyone know know how to change the color of the cite number in the bibliography?

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" 

\begin{document}
How can I change the cite count number to blue~\cite{ref1}?

\label{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting 
\bibliography{Bibliography} 

\end{document}
```

And here is the content of the bib file

```
@article{ref1,
             author = {John Clark},
             title = {Learn to use Latex},
             journal = {Latex Journal},
             volume = {1},
             number = {1}, 
             year = {2014},
             pages = {1-2}  
}
```

How can I change the "[1]" to blue

[image]

Comment: Please show a MWE of your code for see what are you using for work with bibliographies: `bibtex` or `biblatex`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob. What is MWE? I am using natbib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to do it, but here it is:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author = {John Clark},
  title = {Learn to use {\LaTeX}},
  journal = {{\LaTeX} Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
  year = {2014},
  pages = {1-2},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor,xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@lbibitem}
 {\item[\hfil}
 {\item[\hfil\color{red}}
 {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


How can I change the cite count number to blue~\cite{ref1}?

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to avoid clobbering my files, use the external `.bib` file as usual. Change `red` into whatever color you prefer, using the features provided by `xcolor`.

[image]

Comment: Redefine biblabel also work! \def\@biblabel#1{\textcolor{red}{[#1]}}

Comment: Is it possible to do the same for some specific entry, not all of them? I'm using `biber`.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear to me if you want the *citation call-out number* to be set in blue or, instead, you wish to have the number that precedes the corresponding bibliographic entry set in blue.

If it's the former you want, an easy solution involves loading the `hyperref` package, setting its option `colorlinks` to `true`, and specifying the additional option `citecolor=blue`. As a separate (and probably quite important) benefit, the citation callouts will be made into hyperlinks to the corresponding entries.

(In the MWE below I've changed the document class from `book` to `article` purely to enable all output to be typeset on the same page.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Bibliography.bib}
@article{ref1,
             author = {John Clark},
             title = {Learn to use {\LaTeX}},
             journal = {LaTeX Journal},
             volume = {1},
             number = {1}, 
             year = {2014},
             pages = {1-2}  
} 
\end{filecontents*}  
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % Use "unsrtnat" BibTeX style 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Now the cite count numbers are typeset in blue in the body of the text: \cite{ref1}

\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```